# Using external editor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, emacs, editor

I'm trying to use EMACS as the external editor for MATLAB. After following the directions here: [matlab script editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376178/matlab-script-editing) I can get the `matlab-shell` feature working, but I still don't understand how to use EMACS to write scripts.

When I hit `edit` in the MATLAB console and get to EMACS, I don't see any MATLAB-specific features. Where are the syntax highlighting, debugging, etc. options?

Comment: Why not use the Matlab editor? You can customize your shortcuts to be emacs-like (Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts, select "Emacs"), if that's what you're missing.

Comment: Shortcuts aren't really the #1 thing I'm missing. Just wondering how to use Emacs with MATLAB, that's all. I don't care for MATLAB's built-in editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need the matlab-emacs integration from here: http://matlab-emacs.sourceforge.net/ - that should get you syntax highlighting. If you already have that installed, perhaps you need to update your `auto-mode-alist`.

I must admit that while I use emacs extensively for editing, I use the MATLAB editor for debugging.